# Windows does not install any drivers for storage devices

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have Acer Aspire 4253 laptop with windows 7 and fedora 17 installed.

Recently Windows encounters errors while installing device drivers for storage devices. It fails to install drivers for pen drives, portable hard disks and MMC, but other devices like iPod, USB modem are installed without any error.

The device manager shows the devices in disk drives but with an alert symbol. It says in properties

> A driver (service) for this device has been disabled.  An alternate
>   driver may be providing this functionality. (Code 32)

Can anybody help in resolving this issue?

Where could I find alternate drivers for storage devices?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Here are 3 things you can do which may resolve your issue.**

1. Run [Malware Bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org) or [SpyBot S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html) to make sure there isn't anything else (malware/spyware/adware) messing with your system.
2. Update definitions and run a complete virus scan. An additional free online scan at [eSet](http://www.eset.com/us/online-scanner/) just to make sure its all gone might be a good idea.
3. Once you know the system is clean, open an elevated command prompt and run `SFC /SCANNOW` to run the [System File Check](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833). When it is done, reboot.

Comment: Already done those things but of no use

Comment: It would be helpful to have that information in the question so we know what you've already tried. Please [edit] your question to include **ALL** the details so people aren't posting answers that won't help you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to find the missing/invalid drivers for your devices on the web and install them.  After you do that, Windows 7 will find them just fine when you need them.

Comment: Tried. Windows finds the drivers but the problem occurs while installing.

Comment: @ShankarC - Sounds like a system integrity problem, in other words, your Windows installation is corrupt.

Comment: Any solution to resolve  this issue ?

Comment: Find the drivers OUTSIDE of letting windows do this, their drivers are sometimes bad.  Go the manufacturer website and get their drivers and install them manually.

Comment: Problem not with drivers , problem with windows\